# Paypal not working with Currency Switcher

Tags: magento, paypal, currency

I Have a requirement given below....which need to be integrated in magento project.

1. My base currency is INR.
2. Currency Switcher (USD, AUD, INR, EURO) in header.

****3. Paypal as payment gateway on checkout when user select a currency by currency switcher witch is supported by Paypal.****

Please someone suggest me the perfect solution, i want to configure currency switcher and paypal in my magento store.

Comment: Is your issue solved?